# Touch interactive to CorePlot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, touch, core-plot

I'm developing an iPhone Application, that needs a stock chart. I've followed a nice example for [touch interactive to CorePlot](http://blog.essencework.com/post/9413676170/put-some-touch-interactive-to-coreplot-on-ipad-part-2),
Here in this example, it only showing single touch. How can I make it with multiple touch (like iPhone 'Stocks')? Could you please help me?

Comment: What multi-touch gestures do you need to support?

Comment: This is a very similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597487/touch-interactive-to-coreplot

Comment: above question and give link question is same